# How can I set named code byte relative breakpoints?

Tags: gdb

So if I dig into the assembler and set a breakpoint with, say

```
 b *0xbc2a47
```

And then I list my breakpoints, the debugger helpfully tells me

```
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000bc2a47 <testing::internal::ForkingDeathTest::Wait()+131>
```

Is there a syntax that will let me set a breakpoint at the named location testing::internal::ForkingDeathTest::Wait()+131 in a later run, rather than having to discover if ForkingDeathTest::Wait has been loaded at the same place?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a syntax

This seems to work:

```
(gdb) b *(&'testing::internal::ForkingDeathTest::Wait()' + 131)
```

Comment: Yuck! But thanks!